# Python - how to merge few elements of a list into tuples based on indices?

Tags: python

I am looking for a converter function (converter_func) which can take a input list and return a output list. converter_func takes a second parameter, which is the list of tuples with (start index, end index) to combine some of elements of input_lst into tuples.

```
input_lst  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
output_lst = [1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6, 7), 8, 9, 10, (11, 12), 13, 14, 15] 
index_lst  = [(3, 6), (10, 11)]



def converter_func(input_lst, index_lst):    
        ...
       return(output_lst)
```

Comment: It would be more in line with normal python indexing conventions if your `index_lst` consisted of `[(3,7), (10,12)]` to obtain the output shown, i.e. upper value is one _after_ the last index used in the tuple.

Comment: following @alaniwi, you would then call input_lst[idx1:idx2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
def converter_func(input_lst, index_lst):

    output_lst = []

    for (_, prev_end), (start, end) in zip(
            [(None, None)] + index_lst, index_lst):

        output_lst.extend(input_lst[slice(prev_end + 1 if prev_end != None
                                          else None, start)])
        output_lst.append(tuple(input_lst[start: end + 1]))

    output_lst.extend(input_lst[index_lst[-1][1] + 1:])

    return output_lst


print(converter_func([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                     [(3, 6), (10, 11)]))
```

gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6, 7), 8, 9, 10, (11, 12), 13, 14, 15]
```

If the spec were changed to use indexing more in line with python indexing conventions (second element of the 2-tuples in `index_lst` is index the *after* the last index to be used in the tuple), then the code could be simplified to:

```
def converter_func(input_lst, index_lst):

    output_lst = []

    for (_, prev_end), (start, end) in zip(
            [(None, None)] + index_lst, index_lst):

        output_lst.extend(input_lst[slice(prev_end, start)])
        output_lst.append(tuple(input_lst[start:end]))

    output_lst.extend(input_lst[index_lst[-1][1]:])

    return output_lst


print(converter_func([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                     [(3, 7), (10, 12)]))
```

(note the 7 and 12 in place of 6 and 11 above) to get the same result as shown above.

Comment: Thanks a million ton for providing me working code. It is working exactly as I want.